# Emulate Oculus Rift

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

My undergraduate research is about oculus rift, however my college didn't purchase it yet, they must be sure that the project is viable before importing one, due to  importation taxes. I'll develop in unity and I'd like to know if ther's a way to emulate the oculus' gyros and accelerometers.

Comment: _"however my college didn't purchase it yet...due to importation taxes"_ - With resepect, they can't afford 25% of US $350?  Both are less than an iPad.  How accurate will the research be on a device whose major components require hardware gyros and accelerometers.  Won't your results be skewed by virtualisation?

Comment: I live in Brazil, we will pay $350 * 3 + 80% (taxes, approx). And I'm not going to use it for research, just to prove it can be done.

Comment: Also, ofc my college has the money, it's the largest private college in Brazil, they just like to make things more difficult. I don't make the rules, anyway...

Comment: I'm not sure but [this forum post](https://forums.oculus.com/viewtopic.php?t=19089) and [Oculus Unity Integration Guide](http://static.oculus.com/sdk-downloads/documents/OculusUnityIntegrationGuide_0.4.3.pdf) might answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use riftcat to emulate the vive. using vrtk you create a RIFT/VIVE compatible game and test that, if you need position tracking you add PSservice and use the ps 3 controllers.

I have done taht in the past https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=788YDwzbP58

you wont spend more than 50$ on used items.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, maybe this plugin will help.

[VR Mouse Look](http://talesfromtherift.com/unity-vr-editor-mouse-look-script/)

This is a plugin from @peterept, it can help you simulate view in VR by your mouse.